# Remove unused and old targets from drake cache

Tags: drake-r-package

Over time, I have a lot of older targets in my drake cache (`current==FALSE` under `drake_history()`). I've renamed many of my targets over time, so I'm left with targets in `drake_history()` which are `current==TRUE`, however they're not in my current drake `plan`.

Is there a way to clean up the cache to get rid of all older targets (to save space), and also remove any targets (current or otherwise) which are not in my `plan`?

Rahul

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `drake`'s cache has garbage collection. To remove old targets and save space, you can call `drake_gc()` or `drake_cache()$gc()`.

Comment: Thank you @landau. On a different note, is there a way to change the font size in `drake::r_sankey_drake_graph()`?

Comment: Not yet, but it looks possible.

Comment: I forgot: you can pass fontSize and fontFamily to `sankey_drake_graph()` etc. They are not formal arguments, but you can pass them as informal arguments through `...`.

Comment: I tried this today, but it doesn't seem to get rid of targets currently not in the plan. I still see older ones in the plan upon running `drake_gc()`.

Comment: The objects returned by `drake_history() %>% filter(current==FALSE)`.. are these also in the cache? Is there a way to get rid of them to reduce the cache size?

Comment: Those files are in `.drake/drake/history/`. You can prevent `drake` from writing them using `make(history = FALSE)`.